# java project running perfectly in windows 10 but not on centos 7

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, git, maven

I am running a windows desktop app programmed in java. The project also uses maven. I cloned the project from a bitbucket repository on my centos 7 os. I am absolutely sure that the project didn't had any errors when i cloned it. I tried running in on eclipse neon but the project showed a lot of errors. But later when i ran the same project on windows, it was running perfectly fine without a single error. I also tried importing various jar files and maven dependencies but it still showed errors. It just kept me wondering what was different in the windows because it is highly unlikely that a project runs perfectly in windows but not on linux. Can anyone help??

Comment: Honestly, how should anybody answer this question without a crystal ball? The java ecosystem is very friendly, as it provides detailed error messages in almost any situation!

Comment: "it is highly unlikely that a project runs perfectly in windows but not on linux"  Is it?  It depends what it's doing.  And why haven't you posted the error?  For all we know, it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: i am sorry but all the console shows is " could not load call.java". No explicit error message is shown.

Comment: As you all might be knowing that eclipse shows errors simultaneously while we code. So it was of no use to compile it when the eclipse ide itself is showing errors.

Comment: So do you have "call.java" ? Or maybe "Call.java"? Unlike windows, file names on linux are case-sensitive.

Comment: Sry, Call.java. But why will it depend on it. I am not running the program from cmd. I am directly running it from eclipse ide where an option in available to run.

Comment: If you show is the code it would make it easier to answer.

Comment: I have enclosed an image in the answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Windows do not care about uppercase/lowercase in file names.  Linux do.  You must ensure that all files are named correctly for this to work.  A class named "A" must be in "A.java" and not "a.java".  This goes for packages too (directory names).

Load your project in Eclipse on Linux and go to each error.  Ctrl-F1 will suggest things that can be done.  If it includes renaming the file, do that and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks foe the answer but the the call was correctly named Call.java.Let me include an image.